# adb shell escape character for comma

Tags: android, adb

I am emulating a Broadcast Intent via ADB Tool,
One of the intents extras value is a JASON,
The Jason string is broken after the first comma and I'm not getting the rest of the string.

The shell command I am using:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE -n com.example.fx/com.example.fx.utils.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es "custom" "{"time":"2014-12-08T15:11:19,event_type":"m","event_id":"1418051429_1418051479"}"
```

The code I use to get the string from the intent :

```
String payload = intent.getStringExtra("custom");
```

The result I get:

```
 "time:2014-12-08T15:11:19"
```

Does anyone know why this happens and a way around it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `adb shell am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE -n com.example.fx/com.example.fx.utils.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver --es "custom" '{"time":"2014-12-08T15:11:19,event_type":"m","event_id":"1418051429_1418051479"}'`

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, solved it using [`Alex P.`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1778421/alex-p)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375731/adb-shell-escape-character-for-comma/29053693#comment43215718_27375731):

1. Make sure you **switch** the `"` with `'` **and vice versa** in you "raw" JSON strings.
2. Make sure you're **not** using `` ` `` around your strings.
3. Make sure that the outer-most "wrapper" of your string consists of `'`.

### To summarize:

**This *didn't* work**:

```
... --es "data" "{'buttons': [{'interaction': 'open', 'label': 'Show'},
 {'interaction': 'less', 'label': 'Less of this'}]}"
```

**This *did* work**:

```
... --es "data" '{"buttons": [{"interaction": "open", "label": "Show"},
 {"interaction": "less", "label": "Less of this"}]}'
```

Comment: Shouldn't `--es "data" '{"buttons": [{"interaction": "open", "label": "Show"},
 {"interaction": "less", "label": "Less of this"}]'` be `--es "data" '{"buttons": [{"interaction": "open", "label": "Show"},
 {"interaction": "less", "label": "Less of this"}]}'`? I believe there should be a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Firelord Thank you for pointing that out. At first glance it seems to me that you're right and it _is_ in fact a typo. I'll test this later just to make sure and will edit my answer accordingly. If you tell me your version works for you while my doesn't - this could be sufficient "proof". I think this happened because my `"data"` contains other keys besides `'buttons'` so I didn't close the JSON object....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and worked around it by first running adb -e shell, and then sending my broadcasts from that session.